# how to put a list with and image and text above it, next to eachother

Tags: html, css, inline

I am an absolute beginner with html5 and css, literally learned it since 2 days.
I am trying to have list with recipes. In this list I want the name of the recipe, the picture and a link to the actual recipe. I am trying to get this list next to each other together with the images, but whatever I try, the list stays on a seperate line per list item.
I put all the list items in an  in html. in the css file I tried to put the list items inline by doing this:

```
.list-recipes ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I also tried a lot of other things but nothing works, hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Recipes</title>
    <style>
        .list-recipes ul li {
            display: inline;
        }
        .list-recipes ul li p {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list-recipes">
        <ul>
            <li >
                <p>Google</p>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <img  src="https://google.com/favicon.ico" />
            </li>
            <li >
                <p>CSS-Tricks</p>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <img src="https://css-tricks.com/favicon.ico" />
            </li>
            <li >
                <p>Apple</p>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <img src="https://apple.com/favicon.ico" />
            </li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the selector `.list-recipes ul li` to work, the list `ul` needs to be a descendant of an element with class `list-recipes`.

If you include block elements inside `li` you also need to make those elements inline, this is why I added the rule:

```
.list-recipes ul li p {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: @MilePonsi, if you run the code snippet it shows all three recipes on one single line, so it works. You need to elaborate "did not work"